# OpenGL ES 2.0 : flip y-coordinates using perspective projection

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, projection-matrix, frustum

I wonder if there is an easy way to flip the y-coordinates when using perspective projection? The threads about the issue seem to focused on orthographic projection. I am translating my game based on Canvas to OpenGL ES 2.0 and have relatively complex collision detection. And a lot of syntax is based on the y-axis starts from top of the screen with 0 and ends on the bottom of thes screen for instance 2560

```
  @Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {

    game_width = width;
    game_height = height;

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1f;
    final float far = 40.0f;

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference using orthogonal or frustum matrix so the most simple answer would to simply swap the `bottom` and `top` parameters or even set them to whatever you need.

But to look into frustum a bit more:

What this method does is it creates a matrix that will scale the objects depending on the distance from `near`. It is designed so that an object at `near` is scaled by `1.0`. So for instance if you put a rectangle with coordinates `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` as `x` and `y` then `near` as `z` and using no other matrix but the frustum the result will be exactly a full screen rectangle.

Objects that are closer to `near` will usually not be drawn and those further will be scaled linearly depending on all parameters but `far`. The `far` parameter effects nothing but where your objects will stop being drawn. So in most cases there is no difference if you put a very large `far` value but one very important; Effect of having a large `far` value will be precision of depth test. So when using depth buffer ensure that this value is as small as possible but still large enough to see all your objects.

In most cases we define frustum with a field of view as angle. You define constant `near`, `far` and `fov` from which the border parameters are then computed like `right = tan(fov)*near*0.5` and `top = tan(fov)*near*0.5*(viewHeight/viewWidth)`. These are just some examples though as there are many ways to define it.

In your case there is no reason not to define these values as you please. So having something like `left = 0.0`, `right = width`, `bottom = height` and `top = 0.0`. But then you still need to define near and far values which must be positive. Then if your objects are at 0.0 distance then they will all be clipped.

To avoid this it is best if you use a `lookAt` procedure which will generate another matrix that may define "camera" position in your scene. By simply putting it to `z=-near` you should see the objects exactly as with using orthographic projection. The problem now is that if you want to "zoom in" by putting the camera closer to the objects those objects will again not be drawn.

To achieve something like that you need to define some maximum scale for instance `maxZoom = 10.0`. What you would do then is divide all of the border parameters (`top`, `left`...) with that value. You would also apply this scale to the `z` value in your `lookAt` matrix to see the scene as not being zoomed.

So in general to flip the coordinates you may modify the border values or you may play with look at matrix. There are other ways as well but these are pretty standard. I hope this clears up a few things for you.

Comment: Thanks for your long and nice answer - will look into this more and may accept it in due course of time